# History PushState API does not support long fragments in the url

Tags: javascript, html, backbone.js, pushstate

Currently, my application runs on Backbone.js.

The application works fine with the `#` fragments but it is not crawlable by Google bots because of the `#` in the URL.

So, I decided to remove the `#` to make it more SEO friendly. I enabled the History pushState API and added code to prevent the default action. Here is the code snippet that I have while I initialize my router instance.

```
Backbone.history.start({pushState: true});

$(document).on("click", "a", function(e)
        {

            var href = $(e.currentTarget).attr('href');

            var res = Backbone.history.navigate(href,true);
            //if we have an internal route don't call the server
            if(res)
                e.preventDefault();

        });
```

Also, I modified my Apache config to enable mod_rewrite in order to process stateless requests like refreshing the page or opening the page into a new browser window. Here is my Apache config snippet:

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            RewriteEngine on
            RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)[/]?$ /index.html?pathtyped=$1 [QSA,L]
 </IfModule>
```

The problem that I'm facing is that the Application works just fine with short url fragments but they do not work with large fragments. Meaning the follwoing urls work:

`http:server_name/#view1` -> `http:server_name/view1`

`http:server_name/#view2` -> `http:server_name/view2`

`http:server_name/#view3` -> `http:server_name/view3`

But the url with long fragments do not work. (The following don't work):

`http:server_name/#view1/option1` -> `http:server_name/view1/option1`

`http:server_name/#view2/option1/option2` -> `http:server_name/view2/option1/option2`

Any suggestions to solve the problem are highly appreciated. Thanks you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a bit of Googling and eventually stumbled onto [this gist](https://gist.github.com/andfinally/8388113). I tested it out with a minimal Backbone.js app and it seems to support infinitely long stateless entrance into the app:

```text
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index
    RewriteRule .* index.html [L,QSA]
</ifModule>
```

I had to do a bit of reading to fully understand the `RewriteCond` statements, specifically what `!-f`, `-d`, and `!index` are doing. Everything but the `!index` makes sense.

Give it a shot and let me know if it works for you.

Edit: I actually found the above to only work on my Homebrew-installed version of Apache2 on my Mac and not on Debian. Some more Googling yielded this alternative form:

```text
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

I also put together a fully-worked example of a modern Backbone.js app with pushState and stateless entry [here](https://github.com/amoeba/backbone-pushstate-example).

Comment: I actually have found the above worked on my Mac but not on a Linux host so I did some more Googling and found an alternative form. Fully worked example here https://github.com/amoeba/backbone-pushstate-example. Edited my post to show this.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that the application works in a single URL component scenario like `http://server_name/viewX` because the `Backbone.Router` you have defined matches the URL and successfully and makes the callback defined to render `viewX` (without the `#` for modern browsers and web crawlers, and with it for older browsers). So, when it doesn't work, I would imagine that the defined route patterns are not matching the nested URL components as expected, and the rendering callback is not fired.

You might have a look at your `Backbone.Router.routes` hash and be sure your patterns are matching the expected URL components at each depth.  Have a look at the [Backbone documentation on routes](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-routes), particularly the example on optional and nested URL components, and check that your matching pattern is correct.  For instance, a routes hash containing:

```
routes: {
    view(/:option1)(/:option2) : renderView
}
```

should match URLs starting with `view` (or `#view`) and optionally containing one or two sub parameters, like:

- `view/1`
- `view/1/a`
- `#view/1`
- `#view/1/a`

and in the above examples, `option1` would be assigned `1`, and `option2` would be assigned `a`, and would be passed to the callback.

With a route hash like:

```
routes: {
    view/*option1 : renderView
}
```

everything beyond the first `/` would match and be assigned to `option1`, like:

- `view/1/a`
- `#view/1/a`

In both cases above, `option1` would be assigned the string `1/a`, and would be passed to the callback.

Answer (score -1):

Hm...maybe this is helpful (based on phantomJS) : http://traviswimer.com/blog/backbone-seo